# How to pass list of parameter via swagger rest api call in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, swagger

WebApi Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Plan")]
    public IActionResult PostPlan([FromBody]List<Plan> lstPlan)
    {
    }
```

Rest Api AutoGenerated Method Code (Via Swagger)

```
  public async Task<HttpOperationResponse<IList<Plan>>> ApiPostPlanTestPostWithHttpMessagesAsync(string apiVersion, Plan plan = default(Plan), Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
    }
```

In Controller i have added List object but rest api client auto generate Code have only one object (Plan plan = default(Plan)). so i can't able to send list of objects. please advice

Comment: Someone please help for this issue

Comment: can you please elaborate, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: 1.Add Rest API Client from Visual Studio. 2. i will use swagger rest api url    3. instead of list of objects it will create single object (Auto Generated Code)